# Repeated bottle shots on the home page

Tags: image

We have bottle shots on the homepage that are just the same two bottles repeating themselves over and over. How can I change this to include all other wines.

Comment: Hi Romy - can you provide more context? Is this using the Craft CMS example site or do you have your own website you're trying to work with? What are you currently outputting for code, and can you share it?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the familiar sight of repeating bottles on the homepage. It’s like déjà vu all over again. No need to worry, it sounds like just a “case” of forgotten placeholder code lingering around.

Here’s how I suggest you fix this:

1. Figure out where the code for displaying the bottles on the homepage is located.
2. Search for any placeholder code that is causing the same two bottles to repeat. This could be hardcoded references to specific bottles or image URLs.
3. Replace with a query to fetch and output available wines.
4. Test the homepage to ensure that all bottles are displayed correctly.
5. Monitor the homepage to ensure that new wines are shown when added. Bonus points for adding automated tests that verify this!